# Deimos Expecting 'MESOS_SLAVE_PID' in environment variables

Tags: docker, mesos, mesosphere

I am running a Mesos/Deimos cluster using the Python bindings, and I'm getting the following error:

`F0719 03:26:17.994248     7 os.hpp:131] Expecting 'MESOS_SLAVE_PID' in environment variables`

This error shows up in the pailer for the executor in Mesos's web interface. The line above the error indicates that the executor script has started running (my own log message).

The error occurrs when the executor is run from the executor Python script, i.e. with this

```
driver.run()
```

And the error has to do with Mesos expecting the `MESOS_SLAVE_PID` environment variable to be set (see https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/master/src/exec/exec.cpp#L648). However, Deimos does not seem to set this variable by default (at least in this case) within the Docker container (which it should, I think).

EDIT: this seems to be a bug in Deimos itself. Here is the relevant bug report by me: https://github.com/mesosphere/deimos/issues/43

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the demos binary directly? Or did you provide the executor_uri to some framework.
Because normally, the executor is not expected to be launched directly. We specify the executor by providing the executor_uri to the framework. So each time the framework starts a task:

1, Framework will send the executor_uri among other infos to the slave.
2, Slave will use the infos to fetch the executor and then tell the containerizer to set up environments and launch the executor.

FYI:
https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/0ba6b89b7421d426709af5bf89fac138cf0ca63e/src/slave/containerizer/containerizer.cpp#L262

Comment: The remote executor was provided via URI